# PKAddPassButton not showing icon at all

Tags: swift, apple-wallet

Why PKAddPassButton isn't showing icon?
This happens in both cases when button is single line expanding to entire stack view width
and when it is double line inside UIView container with centreX constraint.
Setting frame or width doesn't change anything.

```
private lazy var addPassButton = UIViewFactory.create.container().apply {
        let button = PKAddPassButton()
        $0.addSubview(button)
        
        button.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(16.0)
            make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
```

Comment: In my case icon not showed only on simulator. On real device all works correctly

Comment: Ok I will check it on real physical device. I've always was checking until now on simulator

Comment: if answer correct I can duplicate it to answer and you can approve it))

Comment: Yes it is correct! Thx please duplicate. I've already checked on device and it works as excepted with icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On real device all works correctly. Icon not showing only on simulator.